# Get one row from a target table for each row in a source table, according to some order

Tags: sql

I have tables `source` and `target` defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE source (id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE target (id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY, source_id BIGINT REFERENCES source(id), score INT);
```

I would like a query that returns the `target` with the highest `score` for each `source`.

I can easily get this `target` for a specific `source`:

```
SELECT * FROM target WHERE source_id = ? ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 1;
```

But I would like to use **one** query to return the highest scoring `target` for **every** source.

The simplest way I have found to do this is PostgreSQL specific, and uses the `LATERAL` keyword:

```
SELECT target.*
FROM 
  source, 
  LATERAL (
    SELECT * FROM target
    WHERE source_id = source.id
    ORDER BY score DESC
    LIMIT 1
  ) AS target;
```

Is there a simple way to do this using standard SQL? Perhaps using a `CTE` or a `GROUP BY` clause?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  `LATERAL` **is Standard SQL**, so your specific concern is 100% unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a window function

```
select * 
from (
    select *,
       row_number() over(partition by source_id order by score desc) rn
    from Target
) t
where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query would return all records from table target with the corresponding maximum score per source.

```
    select max(t.score) over (partition by t.source_id) as max_score_per_source, t.* 
    from target t
```

With over() one may specify a window clause, which works similar to group by but doesn't reduce the records for aggregation. In your case it is the better approach. If one wanted to use group by, a joined sub select would work as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think this will still return all the rows in `target`, but I just want one row per distinct `source_id`.

Comment: Yes, indeed I missed the part concerning the single row per source_id. Sorry about that.